# Two alternative element in one independent claim

Tags: claims, epo, claim-construction, embodiments

Can I use two alternative element without broder statement without covers both? (In one independent claim) (In EPO application)

In example, X comprising (A or B) and C (it is an independent apparatus claim)

Further question,

X comprising (A or B) and C wherein "C is configured for Y if invention comprising A" or "C is configured for Z if invention comprising B"

P.S: Combination of A and B and C provides very similar techical effect for both alternatives.
P.S: I cant use broder term covers both A and B

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claims are hard to draft and your approach might not be artful but [alternatives are allowed](https://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/guidelines/e/f_iv_3_7.htm) in EPO claims if they don't get too confusing.

> A claim, whether independent or dependent, may refer to alternatives,
> provided that the number and presentation of alternatives in a single
> claim does not make the claim obscure or difficult to construe and
> provided that the claim meets the requirements of unity (see also F-V,
> 3.2.1 and 3.2). In the case of a claim defining (chemical or non-chemical) alternatives, i.e. a so-called "Markush grouping", unity
> of invention is considered to be present if the alternatives are of a
> similar nature and can fairly be substituted for one another (see F-V,
> 3.2.5).